# Is it possible to pass arguments in the expression of a PropertyModel?

Tags: wicket, wicket-6

I have a model object that has a getter/setter that accepts a `String`.

```
public String getStringValue(String key)
```

I need to know if it is possible to use that getter with a `PropertyModel` and if so how do I do it? An example might look something like this:

```
new PropertyModel<String>(myObj, "StringValue[key]");
```

Comment: I am working with a TextFilteredPropertyColumn, so I would like to figure out a way to handle this in a PropertyModel as changing the type of model would be a lot of rebuilding multiple classes for little benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't built in way to do it. But you can define your own Wicket Model to do it via reflection. 
For example:

```
public class FunctionReflectionReadOnlyModel<T, R> extends AbstractReadOnlyModel<T> {

    private Object object;
    private String functionName;
    private R key;
    private Class<R> keyClass;

    public FunctionReflectionReadOnlyModel(Object object, String expression, Class<R> keyClass) {
        this.object = object;
        this.functionName = getFunctionName(expression);
        this.key = getKey(expression);
        this.keyClass = keyClass;
    }

    @Override
    public T getObject() {
        try {
            Method method = object.getClass().getMethod(functionName, keyClass);
            return (T)method.invoke(object, key);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //process exception
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

You just need implement getFunctionName(String expression) and getKey(String expression) on your needs.

But I think that is better use another variant. It's not particularly what you ask, but it is typified. Also required Java 8.

```
public class FunctionWithKeyReadOnlyModel<T, R> extends AbstractReadOnlyModel<T> {

    private Function<R, T> function;
    private R key;

    public FunctionWithKeyReadOnlyModel(Function<R, T> function, R key) {
        this.function = function;
        this.key = key;
    }

    @Override
    public T getObject() {
        return function.apply(key);
    }
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
new FunctionWithKeyReadOnlyModel(obj::getStringValue, "key");
```

I've read about usage only PropertyModel too late. In this case you can inherit your class from PropertyModel and change getModel/setModel like in example FunctionReflectionReadOnlyModel. So you don't need change other classes API. But if you want all features of PropertyModel (nested objects) you need implement it.

Comment: Looking at your code it looks like that is exactly what I need to happen; however, I don't have the option of simply changing out the model without significant impact on other classes.

Answer (score 2):

As answered by @merz this is not supported by Wicket's PropertyModel, actually by PropertyResolver.

PropertyResolver supports such access if you use a `java.util.Map`:

```
public Map<String, String> getProperty() {return theMap;}
```

Check org.apache.wicket.core.util.lang.PropertyResolver's javadoc.

Comment: Thanks @martin-g. This is the conclusion that I came to as well. I was hoping there was something I wasn't seeing.  I initially tried a Map and it is working accept I am getting the "Couldn't resolve model type" warning in AbstractTextComponent and I can't seem to get rid of it. I am using an IFilterStateLocator<Map<String, Object>> to store multiple filters in my SortableDataProvider. My idea was to see if I could build an IFilterStateLocator that worked like a Map, but handled casting to the type I wanted.

Comment: The warning is fixed for 7.3.0 and 6.22.0 (or 6.23.0).

Comment: Sweet! I checked 7, but I was on an older version!